# Mysql sum row before

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to sum all rows in week1, week 2 and so on and then i want to in the outcome sum row2 with row 1, sum row3 with row 2 and so on.
How can i do? In a while-loop

Database:

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAo6L.jpg)

Outcome right now:

[Outcome right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqOO9.jpg)

I wan´t it to be:

[Wanted outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzy0t.jpg)

```
 $query ="SELECT
         week, 
         sum(field1) AS field1,
         sum(field2) AS field2,
         sum(field3) AS field3
         FROM table_test
         GROUP BY week
         ORDER BY week ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$query);    


    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Week</th>
                <th>Field 1</th>
                <th>Field 2</th>
                <th>Field 3</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>  

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['week'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['field1'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['field2'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['field3'];?></td>
            </tr>

<?php } ?>

        </tbody>

    </table>
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep a set of running totals during your while loop and keep adding the value of the current row's fields to each related total. Then display the current total instead of the row value.

Something like this:

```
$totals = array(0, 0, 0);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $totals[0] += $row['field1'];
  $totals[1] += $row['field2'];
  $totals[2] += $row['field3'];
?>  
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['week'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $totals[0];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $totals[1];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $totals[2];?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
```